# c# message filter keeps "leaking" first 2 keys pressed

Tags: c#, filter, message, autocad

I'm working on a small extension for autocad using its .net api.

I'm trying to filter keys using IMessageFilter. And it "sort of" works. 
the problem is, its "leaking" first 2 keys I press through... and after that it starts working.
I'm not sure where the bug is occurring (tried posting this at autodesk forum to no avail).

as for the "ps2" , its an instance of autocads "paletteset" object which houses UserControls to fit into acad graphic interface.

I'd appreciate any idea as to why the only first 2 keys get leaked, or methods as to why this is occurring.

here's my code:

```
[CommandMethod("TestCheck")]
public void MyTab() 
{
    filter = new MyMessageFilter(ps1, ps2);
    filter.OnNumber+=filter_OnNumber;
    ...
}

private bool keyboardFilterEnabled = false;

public bool KeyboardFilterEnabled
{
    get { return keyboardFilterEnabled; }
    set
        {
            keyboardFilterEnabled = value;

            if (keyboardFilterEnabled == true)
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
            else
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.RemoveMessageFilter(filter);
        }
    }
}

public delegate void NotifyParentDelegate(Keys source);
public class MyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public MyMessageFilter(PaletteSet p1, PaletteSet p2)
        : base()
    {
        PaletteSet ps1 = p1;
        PaletteSet ps2 = p2;
    }


    public event NotifyParentDelegate OnNumber;
    public event NotifyParentDelegate OnLetter;
    public event NotifyParentDelegate OnControl;

    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100; 
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {

        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Check for the Escape keypress
            Keys kc = (Keys)(int)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode;
            if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && kc == Keys.Escape)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && char.IsDigit((char)kc) == true)
            {
                OnNumber(kc);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


    public void filter_OnNumber(Keys source)
    {
        ps2.Focus();
        if (ps2.KeepFocus != true)
        {ps2.KeepFocus=true; }

        formDimensions.input_dimension.Focus();
        //SendKeys.Send(source.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What values are you typing to test this?  Your code only subscribes to the `OnNumber` event in your `MyTab()` method.  Are the first 2 characters being entered not number?

Comment: I'd test it with numbers. by default I'd type 1 2 3 4 5 6... 
"1" and "2" would be passed to Autocad prompt, while "3", "4", "5",... would be sent to "numericUp/Down" control.

only exception to the rule would happen if I'd have the breakpoints in the visual studio, and I'd have to press "continue" in the debugger. 
then the number of "leaks" would be reduced to 0 or 1 - but I still did not figure out the exact pattern. 

So far only hack that comes to mind is to simulate 2 keystrokes by code... but I'd hate to resort to such "cheat" without understanding the problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it change if you use `WM_KEYUP`?

Comment: This shouldn't be your problem, but if you are filtering your messages, then you should return `true` when you want to prevent the message dispatching and `false` when you want to keep it flowing. I'm not sure what you are doing but the logic seems reversed on your example (you are supposed to be *filtering* the messages you process, not the ones you don't)

Comment: I'll try WM_KEYUP and report how it goes.

as for true/false I've  been experimenting with both to see if I can bypass some errors I've been getting.

One concept was to block all keys using "true"... but I then had to figure out how to still catch those keys and dispatch them to the "numericUpDown"... 

the other approach was to "Focus on NumericUpDown" and keep the filter open (false) so that the keys appear in the numericUpDown control, instead in the Autocad prompt.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain of this, it's been a long time, but setting the focus should suppposedly need a message sent to the control too (`WM_SETFOCUS`) to *actually* change the focus, so even if you set the focus after receiving a `WM_KEYDOWN`, your key will be processed before the message queue gets consumed and you have the chance to change the focus to other control

Comment: hm... so a workaround would be to check if the NumUpDown has focus, and forward key if its true? Will give it a try... see how it goes. Thank you. You've given me something to google..., was googles for past 2 days :D

Comment: WM Keyup doesnt change anything.
and as for the WM_SETFOCUS, I tried it, but it also leaks the first 2 keys, but seems to be the right direction. Could you please direct me to a better topic to look into, or give me a tip on what to ask if I'm to make a new stackoverflow topic (dont wanna flood the forum)